# How to break a css file into 2 files

Tags: css

I have a css file . I want to break it into 2 files. I want to do this because there is some css code like global settings like

```
   *{padding: 0; margin: 0;}
```

and then rest of css. This css file is included in many places. But recently i added this css file to a new page and i found out that the above global settings is breaking my layout so i need the file but without these global settings so i decided to break the file into two one containing above code and the other containing rest. Is that good to do this...what other things can be possible,,?

The css file.. [link](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/)

Comment: This will not be possible without using some dynamic code, like php or something similar. You would then catch the call to the css file, find out where it came from and return the desired parts of the file.

Comment: @janoliver - of course its possible. Just include a link for each css file.

Comment: I assumed that he didn't want to change the html code of the calling files.

Comment: @janoliver : you r right...but wont css import works if i just inmport these two new files into my thickbox.css

Comment: @saurabh ranu: I'm sorry, I can't really follow you. I guess the easiest would be to create one new stylesheet and copy everything except the proplem-causing line into it and then just use that one in the one page where the default one doesn't work. Of course, then you would have to keep 2 almost similar css files synched, but that would still be the easiest thing to do. Or, make your problematic page compliant to the default css, which would be the best, since the reset-line should _not_ cause any problems in a well-written website.

Answer (score 4):

Of course it is possible to have multiple CSS files per page. Just make sure you link to all (required) files and it will work.

Grouping sensible CSS styles together in order to make them reusable is a good thing to do as well, so go for it.

Comment: what i did was In break the main thickbox.css file into two css files : globsl.css and rest.css .In global.css the above settings reside and in rest.css the rest of the css in thick box. Then in thick box i did something like import both css file and it now consists of just twp lines...but then i saw the css file is not working...is it right to do that..

Comment: It is better to update your answer and show the code which fail to work properly, so we can see what went wrong.

Comment: see the css link...in some page the above css code *{padding: 0; margin: 0;}
 is causing problem.

Comment: In this link you give the CSS code which is causing problem still resides in `css/global.css`. Your method of including two CSS flies works for me (Opera 11), so if you still have problems it is due to error(s) in the CSS file(s)

Answer (score 1):

You could generate the css dynamically. Passing in a query parameter would let you ouput the "full" css, or just the non-breaking parts:

```
<?php
   header('Content-type: text/css');

   if (isset($_GET['fullmealdeal'])) { ?>
      echo '*{padding: 0; margin: 0}';
   }
} ?>
... rest of the css here ...
```

Then just have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="css.php?fullmealdeal" />
```

in your headers.

Of course, you'd probably want to issue some appropriate cache headers, or most likely the CSS would be fetched for every page request, which'd be a large-ish performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

1. If you are using server-side scripts, you can use two files except make one of them contain everything, and the other contain everything EXCEPT for the global declaration. Then include one or the other.
2. Add a style directly to the pages your worried about, over-riding the external stylesheet. Again, using a server-side script would make this relatively painless.